# Pulling value out of specific javascript object property

Tags: javascript

I have some code which seems to work just fine:

```
async function myfunction(ref) {
  var r1 = await getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-10-03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page");
  var r2 = await getReport(r1.reportID, "get").then(r2 => reportHandler(r1.reportID, r2, 0));
  console.log(r2);
}
```

The `console.log(r2);` outputs this result:

```
{report: {…}, waitSeconds: 0, runSeconds: 0}
report:
data: Array(4)
0:
breakdown: [{…}]
breakdownTotal: ["608674"]
day: 1
month: 10
name: "Mon.  1 Oct. 2018"
year: 2018
__proto__: Object
1:
breakdown: [{…}]
breakdownTotal: ["564566"]
day: 2
month: 10
name: "Tue.  2 Oct. 2018"
year: 2018
```

I'm trying to output the value of 'breakdownTotal' using code I have built using online tutorials

```
const result = data.report.data.reduce((r, e) => {
  e.breakdownTotal.forEach(el => {
    let key = "data";
    if(!r[key]) r[key] = []
    r[key].push(...el.counts)
  })
  return r;
}, {})
```

However, I get this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at myfunction (mytest3.html:12)
```

Comment: You wan the `breakdownTotal` as output right? `r2.breakdownTotal` isn't working?

Comment: There is no JSON here, JSON is a string notation, your just dealing with javascript objects, they're not the same thing

Comment: what's `data` here? how and where do you call this function?

Comment: @Liam data i thought was the structure of the object/json

Comment: ?? I'm not sure what your trying to say. You have no variable called `data` so it's obviously undefined. There is no magic `data` variable

Comment: I think you just need to replace `data` with `r2` if you calling this how I think your calling it.

Comment: also just to reiterate `object !== json`, please don't use them interchangeably (*object/json*), they are different things.

Comment: There's also no jquery in this question.

Answer (score 2):

Return `r2` from `myFunction`

```
async function myfunction(ref) {
  var r1 = await getReport(ref, "queue", "hour", "2018-10-    03", "2018-10-04", "pageviews", "page");
  var r2 = await getReport(r1.reportID, "get").then(r2 =>    reportHandler(r1.reportID, r2, 0));
  return r2;
}
```

Create `data` from `myFunction(ref);`

```
const data= await myFunction(ref);
if(data!=null && data.report.data!=null){
const result = data.report.data.reduce((r, e) => {
  e.breakdownTotal.forEach(el => {
  let key = "data";
   if(!r[key]) r[key] = []
    r[key].push(...el.counts)
  })
  return r;
  }, {})
}
```

Comment: This is also screaming out for some null checking. if `data`, `report` or `report.data` are null it'll break

Comment: So he can put the code of const result with in if statment that check data and data.report.data

Comment: also `const data= await myFunction(ref);`

Comment: It will be best

Comment: @Osama It tells me Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Try to convert your function using async keyword word remove await keyword